# When an iodide/iodate solution is acidified with H2SO4 instead of thiosulfate, why should it be titrated immediately?

Tags: redox, titration

My class is currently performing a reaction to determine the oxidizing power (i.e. the amount of hypochlorite) of household bleach. The general process is as follows:

**Standardize thiosulfate to be used as a titrant of $\ce{I2}$ solution.**

- An excess of I- ions are allowed to react with a known amount of $\ce{KIO3}$ in acidic solution.
- The iodine formed from this reaction is titrated with thiosulfate using starch as an indicator of triiodide anion.
- The relation between moles $\ce{KIO3}$ and thiosulfate is used to determine molarity of thiosulfate.

**Analysis of oxidizing capacity of liquid bleach**

- Excess iodide ion solution added to bleach.
- Iodide ions are oxidized to I2 after this solution is acidified simultaneously with the reduction of hypochlorite.
- The iodine that is formed is then titrated with the above standardized thiosulfate solution.
- The indicator (starch) is not added until the dark-brownish color of the iodine has changed to pale yellow. When it is added, the solution color changes to blue black.
- The end point of titration is indicated when the solution becomes colorless.
- (Note that if the starch is added too soon in the titration, the formation of the blue-black complex is not easily reversed, making the end point very slow and difficult to detect.

**Pertinent reactions are given below**

*Reactions Pertaining to Titration*

$\ce{HOCl + 2I- + H+ -> I2 + Cl- + H2O}$

$\ce{2S2O3^--  + I2 -> 2I- + S4O6^--}$

$\ce{HOCl + 2S2O3^-- + H+ -> Cl- + S4O6^-- + H2O}$ [the addition of the above two reactions]

$\ce{I3- + starch <-> starch*I3-(complex)}$  [blue-black in solution]

*Reactions pertaining to the standardization of thiosulfate*

$\ce{IO3- + 5I- +6H+ -> 3I2 + 3H2O}$

$\ce{3I2 + S2O3^-- -> 6I- + 3S4O6^--}$

### The question

We were told that, during the standardization process, if the **iodate-iodide solution is acidified with $\ce{H2SO4}$, it should be titrated immediately. My question is why?** Using thiosulfate, this is not the case, correct? Why does this change when sulfuric acid is used in its stead?

Answer (score 3):

[After acidification with $\ce{H2SO4}$, starch starts to hydrolyze to its component sugars.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_test) Lugol's iodine does not react with those sugars to form the blue complex.

> Our amylose is gone, today,
>
> Its trace we'll see no more,
>
> For what we thought was $\ce{H2O}$
>
> Was $\ce{H2SO4}$.